# How to design a Java class containing a map of known and unknown key-value pairs?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to design a Java class to hold the results of deserializing a message in JSON format. The message has a simple structure:

```
{
    "appId": "MyApp",
    "action": "Upsert",
    "entityType": "Property",
    "entity": {
        "marketId":   "abc123",
        "propertyId": "def456",
        "name":       "Grand Central Station",
        "hasFoo":     true,
        "hasBar":     false,
        "areaInSf":   30,000
        ... more key-value pairs...
    }
}
```

In the `entity`, the ID and name fields are required and their names are known. There may be an arbitrary number of other properties I also want to deserialize -- they're optional and I don't know all the names ahead of time.

If I only deal with the known fields I can create a Java model like

```
public class Message {
    public String appId;
    public String action;
    public String entityType;
    public Entity entity;
}

public class Entity {
    public String marketId;
    public String propertyId;
    public String name;
}
```

and deserialize the JSON using Jackson like:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Message myMessage = om.readValue(myJsonString, Message.class);
```

But how do I deal with the optional fields in the message? They're flat siblings of the ID and name fields, not a nested map, so I can't do

```
public class Entity {
    public String marketId;
    public String propertyId;
    public String name;
    public Map<String, Object> otherFields;  // hasFoo, hasBar, areaInSf ...
}
```

I prefer a strongly typed `Entity`, so I can validate aspects of the required fields -- min length of ID, etc. Otherwise, `Entity` could just be a `Map<String, Object>`. To get at the fields I'd just loop over the Map's properties. But I want to be able to extract the required fields by name, and only loop over the remainder if possible.

How do I design the Entity POJO so that I can deserialize both the fields declared in the class definition, plus some extra fields found in the input JSON?

Comment: I would say you already have your design, you just need to implement a custom deserializer for it https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: "just" ;-) -- thanks @JorgeCampos, this looks a bit complex but it's nicely encapsulated and looks like it will work (I can do anything I want in the deserializer, just need to exercise my imagination). If you write this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the link -- it's a great article, clear as possible, and builds things up logically.

Comment: The simple approach is to deserialize `entity` to a `Map<String, Object>` then work with that. A custom deserializer would be more elegant though. Another option is to change the schema to put "unknowns" under an inner element, say `properties` whose type is `Map<String, Object>`, then you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: @Bohemian yes, that's my fallback approach, but I won't get the required fields  automatically, I'll have to find and bind them like all the rest. I'm looking for a way to automatically bind the known fields and only do introspection on the optional ones. A custom deserializer looks like a fair bit of work but will do what I want. Now to see if it's worth the effort...

Comment: I've added an answer for you, also added a bit of code for you to use as reference. Hope it helps you achieve your objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is already ready. What you need is a custom Deserializer for it. As linked on the comments here is a good article [Custom Deserialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization#on-mapper)

Translating that article into a piece of code it would be something like (**note** this might not be workable, use as reference as I did not test it):

```
public class MessageDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Message> {

    public MessageDeserializer() {
        super(Message.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Message deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        try {
            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
            Message message = new Message();

            // your known fields
            message.setAppId(node.get("appId").asText());
            message.setAction(node.get("action").asText());
            // .... other fields

            Entity entity = new Entity();
            entity.setMarketId(node.get("entity").get("marketId").asText());
            entity.setPropertyId(node.get("entity").get("propertyId").asText());
            // .... other fields

            Map<String, Object> otherFields = new HashMap<>();
            JsonNode entityNode = node.get("entity");
            final List<String> knownEntityFields = List.of("marketId", "propertyId" /*, others here*/);
            entityNode.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> {
                String fieldName = entry.getKey();
                if ( knownEntityFields.stream().noneMatch(fieldName) ) {
                    otherFields.put(fieldName, entry.getValue());
                }
            });
            entity.setOtherFields(otherFields);

            message.setEntity(entity);
            return message;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You can even make it better by using reflection (some might disagree :) )

Comment: yeah, the magic is in `setOtherFields()`. This is a good starting point for me -- thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

> *"... But how do I deal with the optional fields in the message? They're flat siblings of the ID and name fields, not a nested map ..."*

If the field names are dynamic, just use a *[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)*.

Here is an example using *[Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson)*.

```java
class Entity {
    public String marketId;
    public String propertyId;
    public String name;
    Map<String, Object> m;
}
```

```java
String s
    = '{'
    + "    \"appId\": \"MyApp\","
    + "    \"action\": \"Upsert\","
    + "    \"entityType\": \"Property\","
    + "    \"entity\": {"
    + "        \"marketId\":   \"abc123\","
    + "        \"propertyId\": \"def456\","
    + "        \"name\":       \"Grand Central Station\","
    + "        \"hasFoo\":     true,"
    + "        \"hasBar\":     false,"
    + "        \"areaInSf\":   30000"
    + "    }"
    + '}';
Gson g = new Gson();
JsonElement e = g.fromJson(s, JsonElement.class);
Message m = g.fromJson(e, Message.class);
e = e.getAsJsonObject().get("entity");
m.entity.m = g.<Map<String, Object>>fromJson(e, Map.class);
m.entity.m.remove("marketId");
m.entity.m.remove("propertyId");
m.entity.m.remove("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work without deserializer kung fu:

```
public class Entity extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    public String getMarketId() {
        return get("marketId");
    }
    public String getPropertyId() {
        return get("propertyId");
    }
    public String getName() {
        return get("name");
    }
}
```

The rest of the attributes can be found in `keySet()` or `entrySet()` etc.

Comment: "deserializer kung fu:" I lol at this :D

Comment: yes, and I love how short and clear it is. Actually this might be closer to my need -- I can assign the values directly to a map, but I can also declare these methods in an interface and have subclasses for different entities with different required fields. I think I'll give this a go as well. Thanks!